# QT dbconnection problem

Tags: qt, postgresql

how could I create a connection in QT using PSQL?

Comment: what specifically are you not understanding int the [qt sql](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/sql-connecting.html) documentation?

Comment: im new in pSql so i dont know where to start

Answer (score 1):

You would use the [QT database drivers](http://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/sql-driver.html).